# Moviepy VideoFileClip cutting video off halfway

Tags: python, duration, moviepy

I am currently writing some code in python to take in a .mp4 file, and convert it to a .mp3 file.
However, when I create the instance of `VideoFileClip()`, it shortens my clip (original length: 4:37, VideoFileClip length: 2:16).
I have looked around but cannot find any similar problems.
I am using python 3.7 in pycharm 2018.3

Here is my code for this part:

```
    from moviepy.editor import *

    videoclip = VideoFileClip("/Users/********/*********/input.mp4")
    audioclip = videoclip.audio
    audioclip.write_audiofile("output.mp3")
    audioclip.close()
    videoclip.close()
```

*(path hidden for privacy reasons)*

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

*p.s please comment if I have missed out some information - this is my first post.*

---

In case it makes a difference, here is the entirety of my code:

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
from moviepy.editor import *
import uuid
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3 as mtmp3
print("Packages Imported")

import PySimpleGUI as psg


#############################################################################################################

UID = uuid.uuid4().hex

#############################################################################################################

psg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout =    [[psg.Text("Browse Video File", font='Iceland 60')],
             [psg.Input(key='-IN1-', enable_events=True, visible=False)],
            [psg.FileBrowse(target='-IN1-', size=(20,10), font="Iceland 20")]]

window = psg.Window('Select Video Vile').Layout(layout)

event, values = window.Read()

print(str(values['-IN1-']))

window.close()

InputFilePathMp4 = str(values['-IN1-'])

layout =    [[psg.Text("Browse Destination Folder", font='Iceland 60')],
             [psg.Input(key='-IN2-', enable_events=True, visible=False)],
            [psg.FolderBrowse(target='-IN2-', size=(20,10), font="Iceland 20")]]

window = psg.Window('Select Destination Folder').Layout(layout)

event, values = window.Read()

print(str(values['-IN2-']))

window.close()

OutputDestinationFolder = str(values['-IN2-'])

###########################################################################################################


OutputDestinationFolder = OutputDestinationFolder + "/VideoTranscriber" + UID + "/"
os.mkdir(OutputDestinationFolder)

OutputDestinationFolder = OutputDestinationFolder + UID + ".mp3"

videoclip = VideoFileClip("/Users/*********/***********/input.mp4")
audioclip = videoclip.audio
audioclip.write_audiofile("output.mp3")
audioclip.close()
videoclip.close()

###########################################################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought to tell it how many frames the original has and then tell the new to have the same number of frames.

```
      image_clip = ImageClip(image_path)
      img_width, img_height = image_clip.w, 
           image_cliph
      frame_num = (int)(fps * time)
      img_size = (int(img_width), 
           int(img_height))
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
      video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, 
           fourcc, fps, img_size)
      for index in range(frame_num):
           frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
           frame_suitable = cv2.resize(frame, 
               (img_size[0], img_size[1]), 
               interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
           video.write(frame_suitable)
video.release()
return VideoFileClip(output_video_path)
```

Hopefully that will do it (if you haven't already solved the problem, I know I'm late.)